# How does AST Transformation object works?

Tags: scala, recursion

Can someone help me grasp the transformation object that allows ASTs modification in scala?

There are many examples around the web but I'm having a hard time understanding how the recursion is happening.

E.g. If I have this AST:

```
def foo = {
 true
}
```

or

```
def foo = true
```

And want to transform it to

```
def foo = {
 println("foo")
 true
}
```

How does the transform function should look like. At this point I have something like this:

```
override def transform(tree: Tree) = tree match {
 case defdef @ DefDef(_,_,_,_,_,rhs) => rhs match{
   case b: Block => treeCopy.Block(b, createPrintln :: b.stats, b.expr)           
   case _ => //Manage functions without block
 }
 case t => super.transform(t)
}

private def createPrintln = Apply(Select(Ident("System.out"), newTermName("println")), List(Literal(Constant("foo"))))
```

But does not work, being honest I'm just applying what I see in examples but can't figure out how the tree is being constructed. An explanation "for dummies" would be appreciated.

[Edit]

Senia example is nice, but I'm still stuck when having a little more complex tree like:

```
imports bla.bla
class MyObject{

  val x = 0
  def foo = true
  def foo2 = { 1 }
}
object MyObject
```

Expected result:

```
import bla.bla
class MyObject{

  val x = 0
  def foo = { println("foo"); true }
  def foo2 = { println("foo"); 1 }
}
object MyObject
```

Comment: @senia This may be obvious to people familiar with Scala AST, but to me it is not and I would like to learn more: what is `treeCopy`? What class or interface is `transform` method overriding or implementing? (Could the code here on in the answer be more complete or link to relevant docs?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original `Tree` looks like this:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> showRaw{ reify { def foo = { true } }.tree }
res0: String = Block(List(DefDef(Modifiers(), newTermName("foo"), List(), List(), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(true)))), Literal(Constant(())))
```

Without outer `Block`:

```
scala> showRaw{ reify { def foo = { true } }.tree match { case Block(List(defdef), _) => defdef } }
res1: String = DefDef(Modifiers(), newTermName("foo"), List(), List(), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(true)))
```

So your `rhs` variable isn't a `Block`.

So you should replace `//Manage functions without block` with `Block(createPrintln, t)`

I guess your `transform` method should return `DefDef`, not `Block`.

```
def addPrintln(t: Tree): Block = t match {
  case b :Block => treeCopy.Block(b, createPrintln :: b.stats, b.expr)
  case t => Block(createPrintln, t)
}

override def transform(tree: Tree) = tree match {
  case defdef @ DefDef(mods, name, tparams, vparamss, tpt, rhs) => 
    treeCopy.DefDef(defdef, mods, name, tparams, vparamss, tpt, addPrintln(rhs))
  case t => super.transform(t)
}
```

Test:

```
scala> def createPrintln = Apply(Select(Ident("System.out"), newTermName("println")), List(Literal(Constant("foo"))))
createPrintln: reflect.runtime.universe.Apply

scala> def addPrintln(t: Tree): Block = t match {
     |   case b :Block => treeCopy.Block(b, createPrintln :: b.stats, b.expr)
     |   case t => Block(createPrintln, t)
     | }
addPrintln: (t: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree)reflect.runtime.universe.Block

scala> def transform(tree: Tree) = tree match {
     |   case defdef @ DefDef(mods, name, tparams, vparamss, tpt, rhs) =>
     |     treeCopy.DefDef(defdef, mods, name, tparams, vparamss, tpt, addPrintln(rhs))
     | }
transform: (tree: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree)reflect.runtime.universe.DefDef

scala> val defdef = reify { def foo = { true } }.tree match { case Block(List(defdef), _) => defdef }
defdef: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = def foo = true

scala> transform(defdef )
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.DefDef =
def foo = {
  System.out.println("foo");
  true
}
```

**Upd:**

`super.transform` calls parent implementation. See [internal implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a702b780bb4b6e6684fc39a82119600a027a01b0/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Trees.scala#L1279) for code.

Comment: Tnx senia, your suggestion of refactoring addPrintln is a good advise. What happen if I have a more complex tree where I want to ignore everything that is not a defdef? How does transform method should change in order to recreate the new tree? I have see that in many examples they recur over transform like super.transform(tree) when the match is not an expression that should be modified, but I don't get how after the recursion the tree is recreated. https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm/blob/171be7e/src/main/scala/com/github/retronym/macrocosm/Macrocosm.scala#L129 (look the transform pls)

Comment: Edited the question to show the problematic, I undestand your transform method but it gets confusing when the tree grows. Sorry, I hope not looking lazy and trying to get an easy answer, I really don't get this stuff :(

Comment: It's not a recursive call. It's a call of parent [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a702b780bb4b6e6684fc39a82119600a027a01b0/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L3014).

Comment: Yes you are rigth, I will read the scala implementation of transform in Transormer class to see whats happening in the back 'cause if there's not recursion involved, how is the method transform walking thru the tree?

Comment: @rsan: [there is](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a702b780bb4b6e6684fc39a82119600a027a01b0/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Trees.scala#L1309), for instance, recursive call for "Block".